# Get Azure resource group creation time

Tags: azure, azure-rm

**Intent**: Know when a resource group was created for the first time.  The client organization wants to report and act on resource group creation timestamps. This will be used in automation scripts.

Unfortunately there is no *creation timestamp* property on resource groups.  Using `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup` returns objects like this:

```
ResourceGroupName : eastus2-something-rg
Location          : eastus2
ProvisioningState : Succeeded
Tags              :
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/eastus2-something-rg
```

How do I retrieve the creation timestamp for a resource group?

Comment: Dead URL needs to be removed or updated: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/32424859-creation-date-as-a-first-order-property-for-all-re

Comment: Removed the dead URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get creation date time of Azure Resource Group using below PowerShell cmdlets (AzRestMethod)

```
$subId = (Get-AzContext).Subscription.ID
((Invoke-AzRestMethod -Path "/subscriptions/$subId/resourcegroups?api-version=2020-06-01&`$expand=createdTime" -Method GET).Content|ConvertFrom-Json).value|select name,createdTime
```

Comment: Works for the resource group, does not work for managed AKS cluster, for example.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, resource groups don't have a creation timestamp.

But management operations are recorded in logs, and these logs can be retrieved with the `Get-AzureRmLog` command.

Here is a PowerShell statement that goes through a subscription's resource groups and finds those that were created n or more days ago (from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rcabr/ff3e2a7b92d12e876bfe5d4fdcf89aa1)):

```
$days = 7
$pointInTime = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-$days);
$horizon = $pointInTime.AddDays(-$days);

"===Removing resource groups created between $horizon and $pointInTime==="

# Get potential log entries
$logs = @()
$logs += Get-AzureRmLog -StartTime $horizon -EndTime $pointInTime -Status "Succeeded" -ResourceProvider "Microsoft.Resources" -WarningAction "SilentlyContinue" `
    | Select-Object ResourceGroupName, ResourceId, @{Name="EventNameValue"; Expression={$_.EventName.Value}}, @{Name="OperationNameValue"; Expression={$_.OperationName.Value}}, EventTimestamp, @{Name="HttpVerb"; Expression={$_.HttpRequest.Method}} `
    | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.EventNameValue -EQ "EndRequest" -and $_.OperationNameValue -eq "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write" -and $_.HttpVerb -eq "PUT"} `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName -Unique

"Expired resource groups (created BEFORE $pointInTime) -> $logs"

# Get recent log entries to remove from the list
$nologs = @()
$nologs += Get-AzureRmLog -StartTime $pointInTime -Status "Succeeded" -ResourceProvider "Microsoft.Resources" -WarningAction "SilentlyContinue" `
| Select-Object ResourceGroupName, ResourceId, @{Name="EventNameValue"; Expression={$_.EventName.Value}}, @{Name="OperationNameValue"; Expression={$_.OperationName.Value}}, EventTimestamp, @{Name="HttpVerb"; Expression={$_.HttpRequest.Method}} `
| Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.EventNameValue -EQ "EndRequest" -and $_.OperationNameValue -eq "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write" -and $_.HttpVerb -eq "PUT"} `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName -Unique

"Resource groups created AFTER $pointInTime -> $nologs"

# remove any that were found to have recent creation
$rgs = $logs | Where-Object {$nologs -notcontains $_} | Select-Object @{Name="ResourceGroupName"; Expression={$_}} | Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"

"Existing resource groups to delete -> $($rgs | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName)"

$rgs | Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Force -AsJob
```

It returns a list of the jobs that are running to delete the resource groups (they can take some time depending on their contents).

Comment: The Azure audit logs contain data only for 90 days. Is there any way to fetch data (like RG created time) for RG created sometime last year??

Comment: You could query the deployments. RGs are not recorded in the deployment log, but you could use the earliest resource deployed to the RG, maybe. Also, deployments can be deleted, so you risk that as well.

Comment: I appreciate the solution but it is hacky and makes a lot of assumptions that aren't obvious or inherently true.

Comment: @gigalul Indeed.  And the Powershell modules in this answer from 4.5 years ago are now deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

This information is available via ARM, but you have to call the API directly rather than the PS Get-AzureRmResourceGroup (or Get-AzResourceGroup) cmdlets.

See [Deleting all resources in an Azure Resource Group with age more than x days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707068/deleting-all-resources-in-an-azure-resource-group-with-age-more-than-x-days/58830232#58830232)

Essentially, you need to add the to the $expand=createdTime to your query parameters, ie.:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/1237f4d2-3dce-4b96-ad95-677f764e7123/resourcegroups?api-version=2019-08-01&%24expand=createdTime
```

Comment: Works for the resource group, does not work for managed AKS cluster, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `az group deployment list -g [RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME]` and then parse out the oldest "timestamp" value using any method you'd like.

Note that as of the time of this writing, `az group deployment` is implicitly deprecated and will be replaced by `az deployment group`.